# how to use mysql tree structure query

Tags: mysql, sql, treeview, hierarchical-data, mysql-5.7

I want to select data in tree structure from my database table.

```
id  vendorid    categoryid  parentcategoryid    
1   7            33           0 
2   7            81          33 
3   7           170          81 
4   7           172          81 
5   7           173         172 
6   7            34           0 
7   7            90          34 
8   7            92          34 
9   7            37           0  
10  7           114          37
```

Please suggest . I am using an older version of mysql. I cannot use recursion method.

I want result data in this format:

33->81->170

33->81->172->173

34->90

34->92

Comment: Please show us the results that you want, as tabular text. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have update the same in question.